# AngularJS length filter

Tags: angularjs, filter

How can I show only 2 character length values in select box with `ng-option` filter?

```
ng-options="item.NumberValue as item.Title for item in myLists.list1 | filter:{NumberValue.length:2}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
ng-options="item.NumberValue as item.Title for item in 
    myLists.list1 | filter:3:comparator"
```

And then define comparator in controller:

```
$scope.comparator = function (value, size) {
    return value.length === size;
};
```

See [fiddle](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oddOVw).

Comment: Thanks, how can i do it without funtion?